# How to select certain text nodes using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get some data from a website using ajax.

This is my code with an ajax POST methode:

$(data).find('.col-md-9 .panel:lt(5)').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).find('.panel-body .sp-card td:eq(1) center ').text());

console:

Mc-Wars Network
IP: mc-wars.org
Vote - Server info 
Website

I just want to get the first line : Mc-Wars Network

Please help!

Here is an image of the html code Im scraping.

[image: Html code]

Here is an image of the console after scraping. (I just need the first line.

[image: console]

This is code from the website Im scraping:

```
<div onclick="location.href='//www.serverpact.com/vote-20129 ';" class="panel panel-default sp-plane">
                        <div class="ribbon ribbon-small ribbon-blue">
                            <div class="banner">
                                <div style="font-size: 14px;text-align: center;" class="text">#1</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="padding: 5px;" class="panel-body">
                            <table class="sp-card">
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <td style="font-weight: bold;vertical-align: middle;"><center><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i><br>8384<br><br>#1</center></td>
                                    <td style="font-weight: bold;vertical-align: middle;">
                                        <center>
                                        Mc-Wars Network<br>
                                        <b>IP: mc-wars.org<br>
                                        <a style="margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="//www.serverpact.com/vote-20129 ">Vote - Server info</a> 
                                        <a style="margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="http://mc-wars.org">Website</a>
                                        </b></center>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="500px" class="hidden-xs">
                                    <a href="http://mc-wars.org" target="_blank"><img style="margin-top: 7px;margin-bottom: 3px;border-radius: 4px;" src="http://www.serverpact.com/b/20129.gif" alt="Mc-Wars Network" class="img-responsive hidden-xs"></a>
                                        <span style="font-size: 13px;">
                                            McWars is a minecraft pvp based server where you will have to build a fortress for your team and destroy the other teams base to win. With more than 10 different classes to choose, youll love it.
                                        </span>            
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably text() combines all child text nodes.

What you need is probably to retrieve the text nodes as **nodes** then get their content. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet where I navigate the child nodes of the `center` in the `td` to the proper text node. Note that whitespace creates a child node, so for example before the `center` node theres a whitespace only text node (that doesn't matter in this case but it's something you should be aware of).

```js
document.write('here you go:' + $('#firstDiv td:nth-child(2) center')[0].childNodes[0].textContent)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstDiv">
        <table id="coolTable">
           <tbody>
           <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
              <td>
                    <center>
                       The text I need!
                    <br>
                    <b>
                    The text I dont need!
                    </b>
                    </center>
             </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
    </div>
```

See also: [MDN: Whitespace in the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Whitespace_in_the_DOM)

Comment: How can I let my javascript code to ignore the whitespaces?

Comment: Did you read the article I linked to? It has some utility functions for doing that, like the `first_child( par )`

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do that:

```
$(data).find('#firstDiv #coolTable').each(function () {
console.log($.trim($(this).find('tbody tr td:eq(1) center').contents()[0].nodeValue))});
```

Comment: When I replace the .text() function with .contents()[0].nodeValue I get this error = Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined

Comment: You're using the find method looking for class elements instead id elements as you've defined in your html structure. Only replace your script with the above, once that I already have tested it in order to get it working.

Comment: Regarding the question you've asked to @ekuusela, you can remove the whitespace using the jQuery  method $.trim(' string_here ') as I already use in my answer. Dont forgot to vote up whether it was useful. Thank you!

Comment: The above code was just an example of what I needed to get. I changed my question to were you can see what I really need. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, your question have changed a lot!
Add at the end of your .text() which will do the job:

```
.match(/[^\n]+/g)[0]
```

Note that all lines can be caught by changing the index, where "0" is the first line, "1" the second and successively.

Comment: Nope, I get this error now. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null (It gets all the text when I dont use the .match at the end)

Comment: Can you please post the code and HTML structure so I can try anything here?

Comment: Try to add the .toString() after the .text() method and before the .match().

Comment: adding the tostring gives the same error. Please take a look at the images I posted.

Comment: @Infinity, from what node do you wanna begin to seek? Is this first repeatable?

Comment: I need the first node each time. My js always gives me 4 lines of text. I just need the first line.

Comment: For this case it's just: 'Mc-Wars Network' that I need, but it has to word dynamicly

Comment: Ok! Please, right click on the main node and left click on "Edit as HTML". Select then all the html and post in your answer by using the "{}" code feature of the editor and I'll give you a solution!

Comment: Ok, but give me the full HTML since the node that jQuery will start to look (I think is the element that have a class named "'.col-md-9"). You're trying to get this info by ajax? If true, via GET or POST? I'll build a complete example and post as code snippet.

Comment: I can add all of it because It's to long... I added a part of the html code (should be enough) Please work with this line: $(data).find('.col-md-9 .panel:lt(5)').each(function () {console.log($(this).find('.panel-body .sp-card td:eq(1) center').text());

Comment: Ok, but from where **data** is coming from? By using ajax ($.get or $post)? The parent div (with panel class) have more than an ocurrence, ok? Thank you!

Comment: using ajax POST. Nope there is only one parent div with that class name.